# How to setup multiple environment Dev and Prod for React Native Typescript?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In My application, I am using two different API's for development and production. I want to Implement Like whenever If I pass the command yarn dev iOS then build will generate with development API, Same as well If I pass the command yarn prod iOS build will generate with production API. How to achieve this?

I have tried using react-native-dotenv but not getting much clear idea.

Comment: You can use something like https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: I also use react-native-config and it works really well

Comment: @dianaqqq  Do you have any sample code?

Comment: There are a few steps to follow (with some setup on ios & android) and I think the best explanation you'll find in some well written articles (like this one https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-multiple-environments-on-react-native-for-ios-and-android-c43f3128754f)

Comment: `react-native-dotenv` maintainer here. I'm happy to explain anything if needed!